# Cloud CDN signed url V.S. Cloud Storage signed url?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Cloud Storage signed url doc: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Cloud CDN signed url doc: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls

What's the difference between them? I am confused which one should I use.

Here is my case:

I want to make my bucket and objects from the public to not public which means I will remove `allUsers` member from the permissions.

I am looking for a way that the users of my application can access the objects (images, media) with some authentication. Otherwise, all users on the internet will access my bucket and objects. The users don't need to have Google accounts, so I think `IAM` and `ACL` are not the correct ways.

I am not sure cloud storage signed url is the correct way. And there is another issue is I already stored many URLs in my database with cloud storage object public url like this:

`https://storage.googleapis.com/ez2on/1536250853638-NN.jpg`

When a client(Front-End) try to access this data, how should I do to generate signed url for these old data in my backend?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About signed URLs, internally they work approximately the same, and generate the URL more or less in the same way. Cloud Storage has a built-in CDN, so using Cloud Storage signed URL is enough.

With signed URL you don't need to whitelist users, you only send them the URL and they have access to it for a limited time.

For your use case signed URLs might not be the best option as they have a limited lifetime, so what I suggest is to make your users log in to your app with the app's own logic, not IAM, or just access the app without login (if it is not essential to log in), and then make the app handle the users' requests to Cloud Storage objects through a service account (IAM):

1. `user` (non-Google/Google) logs in to the `app` (app login, not IAM)
2. `user` requests an object presented by the `app` without internal data (bucket's path, etc.)
3. `app` uses its own service account (IAM) to request the object to `Cloud Storage`
4. `Cloud Storage` passes the object to app, app to user

Using this service account workaround you can still use the URLs saved in your database. If you would like to use the signed URL you should modify the database constantly, which is not the optimum.

You can use [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python) to authenticate from your app to Cloud Storage, limiting the access to only your app's service account.
You can set the service account [implicitly](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/auth/cloud-client/snippets.py#L22) or [explicitly](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/auth/cloud-client/snippets.py#L36).

Comment: Thanks. I am confused, I fetched the object in my backend with a service account, how do I pass the object to the frontend, an object url?  I think I should save the object names to the database, not a whole url. And when I send data to the frontend, the frontend should send requests for object URLs use these object names to my backend. Am I correct?

Comment: To the frontend you can pass it directly, serving it, for example in base64, with a print().
It is better not to pass the object URL to the frontend.

Optimally you save the object's path to the database, not the whole URL, and when you request the object you concatenate the base URL (with the bucket's name) with the object's path.

I don't think you are right in the last question: When sending data to the frontend, it should send requests for the objects with their relative paths, and the backend concatenates them with the base URL and requests them to Cloud Storage.

Comment: OK. I don't want to pass base64 encoded image to the frontend, because of its size. Even though my backend requests the whole url of the object using a service account. But the bucket and object are not public. I think frontend get the url like: `https://storage.googleapis.com/ez2on/1536250853638-NN.jpg` from my backend according to API, it still doesn't have the permission to access this object. My backend has permission because of using a service account, my frontend doesn't.  This blocks me.

Comment: Then use signed URLs, the backend generating them and passing them to the frontend, keeping the bucket private in general. I think it is also cheaper to send from Cloud Storage than from App Engine. For example like this: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/1295%23issuecomment-165538396&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1562932220699000&usg=AFQjCNGiwXu_zkKgMHBaB1FkJyWSmHlc5A